# Title doesn't change while using php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a problem which changing Webpage title dynamically using PHP and MySQL.

This code worked for me for about 5 mins and now it doesn't.

When I view the source code, it actually fetches the data but doesn't update the title in the web page.

Can you please suggest?

```
<?php 
    mysql_connect("localhost","admin","admin") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("Table") or die(mysql_error()); 

    $id=$_GET["id"];
    if(!is_numeric($id)){
    echo "Data Error";
    exit;
}

$data=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `Job_ID`=$id");
$row=mysql_fetch_object($data);
echo mysql_error();

echo "<tr><th>Job Title:</th></tr>";
echo"<tr><td>$row->Job_Title</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><th>Website:</th></tr>";
echo"<tr><td>$row->Company_URL</td></tr>";

$pagetitle = $row->Job_Title; 
echo "<title> Required $pagetitle </title>";
```

Comment: echo"<tr><td>".$row->Job_Title."</td></tr>"; replace this and check, henceforth try to press ctrl+z to revert back your changes

Comment: Title tag should be within the header tag, and it should not be preceeded by an html table.

Comment: Please add the _actual_ result and your corresponding expectation.

Comment: You may visit: [link] (http://www.ultimatesearchconsultants.com/jobs.php) now click on any job. It would show page title as [link] (http://ultimatesearchconsultants.com/viewjob.php?id=254) but when you check the source code you will find that <title> fetches the data but doesn't display it on the webpage.

Comment: You link is showing 
Job Title:
Office Sales and Operations Executive right now. is it okay?

Comment: Ok. But on my system its not showing.

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
<?php 
    mysql_connect("localhost","admin","admin") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("Table") or die(mysql_error()); 

    $id = (int) $_GET["id"];
    if(!is_numeric($id)){
        echo "Data Error";
        exit;
    }

    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `Job_ID`=$id");
    $row = mysql_fetch_object($data);

    echo "<html><head><title>Required ".$row->Job_Title."</title></head><body>";

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><th>Job Title:</th></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>".$row->Job_Title."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><th>Website:</th></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>".$row->Company_URL."</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";

    echo "</body></html>";
?>
```

Comment: `echo "<tr><td>".$row->Company_URL."</td></tr>";` is same as `echo "<tr><td>$row->Company_URL</td></tr>";`